# Why doesn't this e-mail display correctly in Lotus Notes?

Tags: php, mime, lotus-notes, multipart, email

I'm building an e-mail with PHP, following the RFC as closely as I can, and this appears to work in other clients (gmail, outlook), but not in Lotus Notes.

The client sees everything including the first boundary and below as raw text.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Delivered-To: to-address
Received: by 10.220.179.196 with SMTP id br4cs92871vcb;
        Wed, 4 Aug 2010 12:43:25 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.142.153.8 with SMTP id a8mr8450322wfe.272.1280951004485;
        Wed, 04 Aug 2010 12:43:24 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <from-address>
Received: from mail.shawcable.com (shawmail.shawcable.com [64.59.128.220])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id u3si21000705wfh.114.2010.08.04.12.43.24;
        Wed, 04 Aug 2010 12:43:24 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 64.59.128.220 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of from-address) client-ip=64.59.128.220;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 64.59.128.220 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of from-address) smtp.mail=from-address
Received: from bpd2mi4no-svcs.prod.shawcable.com ([10.0.184.123])
  by bpd2mo3no-ssvc.prod.shawcable.com with ESMTP; 04 Aug 2010 13:43:23 -0600
X-Cloudmark-SP-Filtered: true
X-Cloudmark-SP-Result: v=1.0 c=1 a=j-HvEyuwSbsA:10 a=jPJDawAOAc8A:10 a=VphdPIyG4kEA:10
 a=723qJf0nrfPCVscgoneiVQ==:17 a=XNncB39hAAAA:8 a=9_hLDayX4C4LLl8a-0MA:9
 a=59rYzRZNn7tR2Ks0X5EEmGNsDccA:4 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=W6m-oQNjxE0A:10
 a=m0e0AD9m6KYA:10 a=qiWi7Edwir4A:10 a=NWVoK91CQyQA:10 a=Nv_7JwUJoJt3qdMp:21
 a=VO-zNgdvODOxz_Wt:21 a=AKMAat870XDnGGob1ocA:9
 a=wNVegoG-qe2byXL9BpVchjBMIawA:4
X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="4.55,317,1278309600"; 
   d="scan'208";a="246148948"
Received: from unknown (HELO bpd2mi4no-cmts.prod.shawcable.com) ([192.168.183.123])
  by bpd2mi4no-cmts.prod.shawcable.com with ESMTP; 04 Aug 2010 13:43:23 -0600
X-reinject: true
Received: from unknown (HELO mail.shawcable.com) ([IP])
  by bpd2mi4no-dmz.prod.shawcable.com with ESMTP; 04 Aug 2010 13:43:23 -0600
Received: from Internal-IP (Internal-IP) by sending-email-server
 (E-mail-Internal-IP) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 8.1.436.0; Wed, 4 Aug 2010
 13:43:19 -0600
Date: Wed, 4 Aug 2010 13:43:19 -0600
To: to-address
From: System Admin <from-address>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?test test1?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="qcodo_alt_boundary_28080009bc659404d34ade2f9d7c2bbe"
Message-ID: <27c31e2a-cbb8-4199-978d-1e0b370bacd7@internal-server>
Return-Path: from-address

--qcodo_alt_boundary_28080009bc659404d34ade2f9d7c2bbe
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Development FiLMS The name of this FiLMS install (Development FiLMS)=0D=0Ah=
ttp://Internal-IP The URL of this FiLMS install (http://Internal-IP/dev_r=
yan)=0D=0Atest1 The Username for the user=0D=0A Test 1 T=
he text used to describe this User throughout the system=0D=0AEnglish This =
user's primary language.=0D=0ASandbox (Test Organization) The Name of the O=
rganization this User belongs to.=0D=0ALearner The Name of the Role this Us=
er has been assigned.=0D=0A The Hint that is shown to this user if they do =
not enter their password correctly=0D=0ATrue If the User is able to log int=
o the system, and if they appear in reports.=0D=0ANone The time (if any) wh=
en this User will automatically become inactive.=0D=0Ato-address E-Mail=
=0D=0A[Department] Department=0D=0A[GEO] GEO=0D=0A[Position] Position=0D=0A=
[Access Type] Access Type=0D=0A[Direct Manager] Direct Manager=0D=0A The us=
er's Company Name=0D=0A[temp_password] The field where a user's temp passwo=
rd is stored=0D=0A[Job Family] Job Family is required by Nexen Integrity to=
 direct the SOC survey=0D=0A[Contractor User Id] This User's Id in the cont=
ractor portal.=0D=0Afalse If this user should change their password after t=
heir next login.=0D=0A[Employee ID] This User's Employee ID=0D=0A[Bank] Thi=
s User's Bank=0D=0A[Country] This User's country=0D=0A

--qcodo_alt_boundary_28080009bc659404d34ade2f9d7c2bbe
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<ul id=3D"c16">=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">Development FiLMS</s=
pan> The name of this FiLMS install (Development FiLMS) </li>=0D=0A<li><spa=
n class=3D"inlineHeading">http://Internal-IP</span> The URL of this FiLMS =
install (http://Internal-IP/dev) </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inline=
Heading">test1</span> The Username for the user </li>=0D=0A<li><spa=
n class=3D"inlineHeading">Ryan Peters Test 1</span> The text used to descri=
be this User throughout the system </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHead=
ing">English</span> This user's primary language. </li>=0D=0A<li><span clas=
s=3D"inlineHeading">Sandbox (Test Organization)</span> The Name of the Orga=
nization this User belongs to. </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading"=
>Learner</span> The Name of the Role this User has been assigned. </li>=0D=
=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading"></span> The Hint that is shown to this=
 user if they do not enter their password correctly </li>=0D=0A<li><span cl=
ass=3D"inlineHeading">True</span> If the User is able to log into the syste=
m, and if they appear in reports. </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeadi=
ng">None</span> The time (if any) when this User will automatically become =
inactive. </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">to-address</span=
> E-Mail </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[Department]</span> D=
epartment </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[GEO]</span> GEO </l=
i>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[Position]</span> Position </li>=
=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[Access Type]</span> Access Type </=
li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[Direct Manager]</span> Direct M=
anager </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading"></span> The user's Comp=
any Name </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[temp_password]</span=
> The field where a user's temp password is stored </li>=0D=0A<li><span cla=
ss=3D"inlineHeading">[Job Family]</span> Job Family is required by Nexen In=
tegrity to direct the SOC survey </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeadin=
g">[Contractor User Id]</span> This User's Id in the contractor portal. </l=
i>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D"inlineHeading">false</span> If this user should =
change their password after their next login. </li>=0D=0A<li><span class=3D=
"inlineHeading">[Employee ID]</span> This User's Employee ID </li>=0D=0A<li=
><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[Bank]</span> This User's Bank </li>=0D=0A<l=
i><span class=3D"inlineHeading">[Country]</span> This User's country</li>=
=0D=0A</ul>

--qcodo_alt_boundary_28080009bc659404d34ade2f9d7c2bbe--
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the recipient's Person document in Lotus Notes and try changing the "Format preference for incoming mail" option to "Prefers MIME" to see if that helps.

Also look for errors in the Domino log.  It might explain more about the conversion problem.

Comment: I don't think we can get access to the domino log, and I believe the option is already set to Prefers MIME.

Is there anything wrong with the way we're creating the e-mail? They are able to receive HTML e-mails generated with Outlook correctly, but I do not see a difference in the way they are encoded.